# Eclipse config for Java Script

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I am new to Eclipse - inherited unfinished project after employee who left. I downloaded war file and by trial and error installed missing components till it actually built app. I can edit java files, but when I try to open java script files, I get error:

```
Could not open visual page editor
no more handles
could not load SWT library
no swt-xulrunner-gtk-4234 in java.library.path
```

Linux Fedora 17, Eclipse Juno, SWT is reported as installed by yum. `~/.swt/lib/` is empty

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have the proper library to load browser widgets in your Eclipse, that is what `swt-xulrunner` refers to. [This FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#specifyxulrunner) should help you.

What it is saying is that you need to start Eclipse with the following system property:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=<path_to_xulrunner>
```

There should be a xulrunner already included in your Eclipse, but if not, you will need to [download a new one from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XULRunner).

Also, it could be that you are using the Ubuntu pre-packaged Eclipse.  I would avoid doing that.  This pre-packaged eclipse often has some missing things in it. I'd instead recommend downloading directly from [Eclipse.org](http://eclipse.org/downloads)